# ExecuteNonQuery Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: sql

```
sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(Title,Seats,Payment,DateNTime)"+
            "VALUES ('"+ movieName+"',"+numTickets+",'"+creditCardType+"',"+DateTime.Now+")", sqlConnection1);
        sqlCommand1.Connection.Open();
        sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCommand1.Connection.Close();
```

No idea what's wrong with this piece of code. Title and Payment are stored as nvarchar types, Seats as an int and DateNTime as DateTime.
Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings into sql statements. This will protect you from sql injection attacks as well as solve your syntax error problem.

Comment: Which RDBMS (vendor and version)? All of them have a function to get the current time (e.g. GETDATE() in SQL Server)...

Comment: could you please debug this statement and post here what is in "sqlCommand1" variable?

Comment: Hi Jadenkun! Is this issue solved? Do you need further help?

Comment: @Shnugo Solved. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Need quotes for dates as well:

```
,'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "')"
```

But this is very dangerous code you know. You really should use parametrized query for such things!

You will be in trouble if user enters in Title textbox something like this:

> some text', 1, 1, '20100101'); drop table dbo.Orders--

And you are fired the same day.

Comment: @Shnugo, might be, he will simply change that I hope :)

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri That worked! thanks! What about the time? Becuase it only shows me the date. If I want to see both the date and the time, do I need to write "yyyyMMddHHmm"? something like that?

Comment: @Jadenkun, first try  `DateTime.Now.ToString()`, if not then  `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Very likely the error lies here:

```
... ,"+DateTime.Now+")"
```

You must make sure, that the string expression for DateTime.Now is parseable in SQL.

1. Do not put your values into the SQL comman (read about SQL injection)
2. Read about parameters and how to pass them
3. Never rely on culture dependant date-time-formats... (read about ISO8601 or ODBC)

Answer (score 1):

Guessing this is called from c# code, you should use parameters instead of concatenating strings into sql statements.

This will both protect you from [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks and fix your syntax error:

This code should probably work for you, though it's written right here and I didn't test it:

```
using (var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    using (var sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(Title,Seats,Payment,DateNTime)" +
    "VALUES (@movieName, @numTickets, @creditCardType, @DateTime.Now)", sqlConnection1))
    {
        sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@movieName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = movieName;
        sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@numTickets", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = numTickets;
        sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@creditCardType", SqlDbType.Int).Value = creditCardType;
        sqlCommand1.Parameters.Add("@movieName", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

        sqlCommand1.Connection.Open();
        sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following

```
sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(Title,Seats,Payment,DateNTime)"+
            "VALUES ('"+ movieName+"',"+numTickets+",'"+creditCardType+"','"+DateTime.Now+"')", sqlConnection1);
        sqlCommand1.Connection.Open();
        sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCommand1.Connection.Close();
```

Even after that modification, if you are getting error, please tell datatype of Title,Seats,Payment,DateNTime

Answer (score 0):

You have format date part also.

```
    sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Orders(Title,Seats,Payment,DateNTime)"+
        "VALUES ('"+ movieName+"',"+numTickets+",'"+creditCardType+"','"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+"')", sqlConnection1);
    sqlCommand1.Connection.Open();
    sqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlCommand1.Connection.Close();
```